# Set up private yum repo with basic auth

Tags: repository, basic-authentication, yum

I have set my own private yum repo. This is an HTTP base repo with a Apache as a web server, so I would like to add some kind of authentication. Is this something I need to do with Apache or is there anything I can do with the createrepo library to specify a user-name and password?
The final goal is to have several repos:

Dev-Repo, QA-Repo, Staging-Repo, and Production-Repo

I want developers to have access to only the dev-repo, have QA access only QA-Repo and so on...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To setup basic auth on server side, follow http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking (paths might differ - they surely do on mine Fedora installation).

To setup yum to consume that repo you can add either:

```
baseurl=http://user:pass@example.com/myrepo/Dev-Repo
```

or:

```
username=user
password=pass
```

to repo's config `/etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo-DevRepo.repo` (taken from https://serverfault.com/questions/609548/yum-repo-basic-auth-not-working).

Answer (score -1):

Check out OpenRepo: https://github.com/openkilt/openrepo

This is an open source package hosting server that can make packages available for both Debian (APT) and Red Hat (RPM) files.

Each repo can be configured with different permissions.  For example, the QA repo can have write access only for QA users, etc.