# How can i do login at sonattype nexus3 by line command

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I have a VM with Nexus3 running on it.
I already config a yum-proxy repository.
In another VM I want to run yum update by nexus proxy.

If i put my username and password at my /etc/yum.repos.d/nexus.repo everything is going well.

But i don't like to keep my password in plain text.

Is there another way to login on nexus? something similar to `yum login -u jhonatan.morais nexus.mydomain.com:8081`

Comment: Do you really need authentication to read the proxy repo ? Unless it proxies an other private repo, looks like an overkill. Can't you just set it to anonymous read ? I don't know any way of encrypting this info. Your username/password will always be somewhere in clear text. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685560/set-up-private-yum-repo-with-basic-auth

Comment: Unless Redhat has fixed something, using url encoded passwords is the only option:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464848-Authenticated-Access-to-Nexus-from-Yum-Doesn-t-Work

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator I'll try anonymous readind. Thankyou.